# Preparing for Bitcoin Gold

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

I have been holding a small amount of bitcoins on Coinbase and am deciding to move it to wallet.

I wanted to be prepared for the Bitcoin Gold fork coming up in October and was curious about the best approach to go about this so I can eventually get my equivalent Bitcoin Gold (instead of donating it to the exchange)!

If I move my BTC off the exchange/Coinbase and into a wallet, I now officially own it since I have the private key.

If I wanted to take advantage of receiving Bitcoin Gold, I would want to make this move before Oct 25 (obviously smart to move it to a wallet anyway, but I digress..)

After that, I'm a little confused what to do to actually get BTG. I understand someone needs to support it, but what is everyone else doing?

Thanks, hope someone can clarify how to proceed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes Coinbase has not mentioned supporting Bitcoin Gold or Not so to be safe definitely move your BTC to a wallet so you have control of your private keys.

On Oct 25th the fork will happen and on November 1st you will be able to access your BTG Bitcoin Gold by using your private keys.

Here is a video explaining this better...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=natH7Chtv40

Here is the Bitcoin Gold Web site: http://btcgpu.org/

Comment: Any ideas what exchange I can sell it on?

Comment: No exchanges currently list Bitcoin Gold that I know of. We will need to watch this once the fork happens and more information is released.

Comment: Also here is a new video I posted about some weird issues going on with Bitcoin Gold... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3z-jnEtkXlM